# Is it valid to delete a lambda while executing it?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

Is it allowed to delete a lambda object while executing the associated lambda function, as long as precautions are taken not to access any of the captured state after the deletion?

Consider the following example:

```cpp
int main() {
    int x = 1;

    std::function<void()> d;

    auto l = new auto([x, &d]() { 
        fmt::print("x is {}\n", x);
        d();
        fmt::print("I'm deleted\n");
    });

    d = [l](){ delete l; };

    (*l)();
}
```

Here, the lambda pointed to by `l` deletes itself using a Rube Goldberg-like approach through the `d` function<sup>1</sup>. After the deletion it prints a fixed message which doesn't access any captured state.

Is it defined behavior?

---

<sup>1</sup> I couldn't figure out a better way to break the circular dependency between the lambda code which needs to see something that points to itself: I'm open to better options.

Comment: It's great that you are open to better options, but it is difficult to suggest better options without knowing what you are *trying* to do.   I am assuming your real-world task is not to "set up a Rube Goldberg machine", yes?  So, what is the plan?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This has defined behavior in member functions of usual classes. Is there any particular reason you think this may be different in a lambda? I don't see anything relevant.

Comment: @Joe - sorry the "better options" part was about a simpler example where a lambda can delete itself, not about a better option for my higher level problem. I have no higher level problem, I am just interested in this answer to the question as posed.

Comment: @user17732522 - no, I have no particular reason to believe it would be different in a lambda, but I suppose it could be based on the language which allows it for regular member functions.

Comment: @user17732522 - one implication for lambdas not explored here but which was part of the motivation for this question is `this`-capture. If you are inside a deleted lambda the captured `this` would not be safe to use, but if instead you make a member function call which then deletes the lambda, it _should_ be safe to use because you are now using the `this` pointer passed by value in a member function, and this is very confusing because those two scenarios are difficult to distinguish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might not be an explicit specification for this in the standard.

Although not specified to be so, lambda types are "essentially" like special classes. Staying with this analogy, the question would be same as "Is it well defined to `delete this;`". The [typical answer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) to that question is:

> As long as you’re careful, it’s okay (not evil) for an object to commit suicide (delete this).
>
> Here’s how I define “careful”:
>
> 1. You must be absolutely 100% positively sure that this object was allocated via new (not by new[], nor by placement new, nor a local object on the stack, nor a namespace-scope / global, nor a member of another object; but by plain ordinary new).
> 2. You must be absolutely 100% positively sure that your member function will be the last member function invoked on this object.
> 3. You must be absolutely 100% positively sure that the rest of your member function (after the delete this line) doesn’t touch any piece of this object (including calling any other member functions or touching any data members). This includes code that will run in destructors for any objects allocated on the stack that are still alive.
> 4. You must be absolutely 100% positively sure that no one even touches the this pointer itself after the delete this line. In other words, you must not examine it, compare it with another pointer, compare it with nullptr, print it, cast it, do anything with it.

To translate these points to lambdas, "call a member function" becomes "call the lambda", "any data members" becomes "any capture". Your example satisfies all of the points.